group default vars in roles
Is it possible to have group vars defined in roles?
For example I have the following structure in my role repo:
my_repo
|-defaults
| |-main.yml
| |-debian.yml
| |-redhat.yml

In debian.yml I have defined a variable called ssh-package as well in redhat.yml but with different values.
If I install my role with ansible-galaxy and I have hosts defined in group redhat or debian, they wont pickup the variables. Do I need to specify the roles variables inside my target structure?

The statement in Role directory structure is horrible

Directories defaults and vars may also include nested directories. If your variables file is a directory, Ansible reads all variables files and directories inside in alphabetical order. If a nested directory contains variables files as well as directories, Ansible reads the directories first. Below is an example of a vars/main directory

IMO, you can put default variables into the files in the directory defaults/main instead of the file defaults/main.yml. This is what the above statement tries to describe. Other directories and files will be ignored. For example, given the inventory
shell> cat hosts
host_A
[debian]
host_B
host_D
[redhat]
host_C
host_D

Create the role my_repo
shell> tree roles
roles
└── my_repo
    ├── defaults
    │   ├── debian.yml
    │   ├── main.yml
    │   └── redhat.yml
    └── tasks

shell> cat roles/my_repo/defaults/main.yml 
test_var: defaults

shell > cat roles/my_repo/defaults/debian.yml 
test_var: debian

shell > cat roles/my_repo/defaults/redhat.yml 
test_var: redhat

shell> cat roles/my_repo/tasks/main.yml
- debug:
    msg: |
      test_var: {{ test_var }}
      group_names: {{ group_names }}

The play
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all

  roles:
    - my_repo

gives (abridged)
ok: [host_A] => 
  msg: |-
    test_var: defaults
    group_names: ['ungrouped']
ok: [host_B] => 
  msg: |-
    test_var: defaults
    group_names: ['debian']
ok: [host_D] => 
  msg: |-
    test_var: defaults
    group_names: ['debian', 'redhat']
ok: [host_C] => 
  msg: |-
    test_var: defaults
    group_names: ['redhat']

All values of test_var are defaults because only roles/my_repo/defaults/main.yml was included.
What will be the best option to include debian.yml and redhat.yml? Look at the Resolving local relative paths

Ansible tries to find the file in the following order: In the current role. In its appropriate subdirectory: “files”, “vars”, “templates”, or “tasks”; depending on the kind of file Ansible is searching for...

Knowing this, let's put the debian.yml and redhat.yml files into the directory vars. Remember, the files will be ignored if not in the directory vars/main
shell> tree roles/
roles/
└── my_repo
    ├── defaults
    │   └── main.yml
    ├── tasks
    │   └── main.yml
    └── vars
        ├── debian.yml
        └── redhat.yml

Use include_vars
shell> cat roles/my_repo/tasks/main.yml
- include_vars: "vars/{{ item }}.yml"
  loop: "{{ group_names | difference(['ungrouped']) }}"
- debug:
    msg: |
      test_var: {{ test_var }}
      group_names: {{ group_names }}

gives (abridged)
ok: [host_A] => 
  msg: |-
    test_var: defaults
    group_names: ['ungrouped']
ok: [host_B] => 
  msg: |-
    test_var: debian
    group_names: ['debian']
ok: [host_D] => 
  msg: |-
    test_var: redhat
    group_names: ['debian', 'redhat']
ok: [host_C] => 
  msg: |-
    test_var: redhat
    group_names: ['redhat']

Notes:

See group_names

See Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?

You can omit the directory vars in include_vars


- include_vars: "{{ item }}.yml"


You can put the conditional declarations into defaults/main.yml

shell> tree roles/my_repo
roles/my_repo
├── defaults
│   └── main.yml
└── tasks
    └── main.yml

shell> cat roles/my_repo/defaults/main.yml 
test_var: |
  {% if 'redhat' in group_names %}
  redhat
  {% elif 'debian' in group_names %}
  debian
  {% else %}
  default
  {% endif %}

Then, the include_vars task is not needed. The below debug will give the same results
shell> cat roles/my_repo/tasks/main.yml
- debug:
    msg: |
      test_var: {{ test_var }}
      group_names: {{ group_names }}


So the only drawback by this approach is the precedence of those variables have a high priority and they could only be changed via extra flag?

include_vars (18.) can be overridden by precedences 19.-22. Optionally, you can put the conditional declarations into defaults/main (2). I added an example.

Ok I see, I cross referenced this gist and tested the following approach: https://gist.github.com/JM1/9363beeb9fb5055e054b5f64aea0a598?permalink_comment_id=4862192#gistcomment-4862192. It was mentioned there, about the draw backs for include_vars. I have to say that I like your approach more since I control the distribution via the inventory, but I think we are at a point of personal preference and no longer right or wrong.

This answer is about options. The conditional declarations can be used in any precedence 2.-17. include_vars (18.) is the first option to iterate group_names. In Ansible there are always many rights and wrongs depending on many details. There are many strategies, for example, including OS-specific variables incrementally.

love your last commit on the link
